# Does every uncountable proper subset of R has a dense subset ?

Tags: real-analysis

Actually I have got an answer in the negative , that's the Cantor Set , uncountable proper subset of R , nowhere dense . But I tried some of the other subsets , I found that it happens . So I am eager to get a negative example , apart from the Cantor Set , if there exists such .

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2231082/310244), for a general construction of non-cantor set examples.

Comment: If I understand your question then  $[0,1]$ is an obvious example.